# JGroups RPC - Concurrent invocation from same source

Tags: java, rpc, jgroups

We are currently investigating JGroups in a multi-node environment for internal communication and member discovery.

We are heavily relying on RPC, from event transmission to service consumption among the nodes are done via RPC, so JGroups `RpcDispatcher` is our preferred option. But we have found that, concurrent remote method invocations through `RpcDospatcher` are performed in FIFO order when the invoker is same JVM. This behavior is stated in JGroups documentation too, we found.

Is there any way (or configuration parameter) to make `RpcDispatcher` invoking remote methods concurrently from the same JVM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Message.Flag.OOB in your RequestOptions passed to the RPC.